# Default value in selectOption not getting rendered on VF page, but is correct on controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, default-value

My product variable is getting set correctly in the controller - but fails to render correctly on the VF page. This is just a snippet, but there is a LOT going on on the VF page - so that may very well be the problem.

I am wondering, however, if there isn't a better way to set the default value to the first real value (not --none--) of a selectoption by using options[1].getValue()?

VF Page Snippet -

```
<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Product"/>
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!product}" id="productList">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!products}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="primaryDiag, sDiag"/> 
        </apex:selectList> 
    </apex:actionRegion>      
</apex:pageblockSectionItem>
<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Primary Diagnosis"/>
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!primaryDiag}" id="primaryDiag">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!diagnoses}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageblockSectionItem>
<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Secondary Diagnosis"/>
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!secondaryDiag}" id="sDiag">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!diagnoses}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageblockSectionItem>
```

Class Snippet -

```
public String product {get; set;}
public String primaryDiag {get; set;}
public String secondaryDiag {get; set;}

public List<SelectOption> getProducts() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));

    if (userContext.Role_gne__c == 'IFRM') {
        options.add(new SelectOption('Product A','Product A'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Product B','Product B'));
    } else if (userContext.Role_gne__c == 'RFRM') {
        options.add(new SelectOption('Product C','Product C'));
    } // more else if chains here based on userContext

    product = options[1].getValue(); // setting the value, i'm getting the correct values below for Product A but
                                     // picklist value on VF page remains at --None--?
    return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getDiagnoses() {
    system.debug('**getDiagnoses product**: '+ product); // this is getting set correctly
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));

    if (product == 'Product A') {
        options.add(new SelectOption('123.45','123.45'));
    } // else if chains

    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the controller to populate the default product value in either the constructor or the product's setter.  The issue (I believe) is that the product getter is called prior to the getter of the options list, hence why the default option is not correct.

If you end up moving the default product logic, you'll also have to move the declaration for the options list in your controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried the following code :

```
<apex:page controller="test_me_con">
<apex:form >
  <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!product}" id="productList">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!products}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="primaryDiag, sDiag"/> 
        </apex:selectList>
</apex:form>        
</apex:page>
```

public with sharing class test_me_con {
public String product {get; set;}

```
public List<SelectOption> getProducts() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Product A','Product A'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Product B','Product B'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Product C','Product C'));
    product = options[2].getValue(); // setting the value, i'm getting the correct values below for Product A but
                                     // picklist value on VF page remains at --None--?
    return options;
}
}
```

the default was pointing to

[image]

Are you seeing any values in the picklist that the -- None -- value?

Do a system.debug before the `return options` to see what is being returned by the method.

The above behavior shows that somewhere in the code the **userContext.Role_gne__c is not either being queried** in the query that picks the role **(or) the role is not matching one of the above conditions** can u post the query/ method how you get the usercontext.role_gne__c?

Comment: userContext is getting set correctly in a util class. I can confirm that I've tested this prior (like your example) with an empty page and product is being set on the VF side correctly (with using userContext). I'm looking more for a different approach with setting the product variable - currently looking at moving this to the constructor ...or something else